# Need some advice about sql

Tags: sql

I need some help or advice with the following:

I have one Table with 2 columns.

```
=================================
ID           Name
=================================
=================================
1            Denzel
=================================
2            Frozen
=================================
3            Lammer
=================================
4            James
=================================
5            James
=================================
6            Lolipop
=================================
```

As you can see "James" Has same name but different ID. 
My question what is the best way to get "James" Also ID 4.

Should i use compare or??

Update!!

Thank you for you help.

I tried the code like below. But i do get an error.

```
Dim shape As String = ofd.FileName
Dim fi As New IO.FileInfo(shape)
Dim cn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Extended Properties=dBase IV;Data Source='" _
& fi.DirectoryName & "'")
cn.Open()
Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("select min(id) as materialid,material from Coverage group by material having count(*) > 1", cn)
'Manual change
'Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("Update Coverage set materialid=" & TextBox2.Text & " Where materialid=" & TextBox3.Text & "", cn)
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
cmd.Dispose()
cn.Close()
```

But i get the following error:

Values ​​for one or more of the required parameters are missing.

What am i missing?

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: That is not a SQL question any more. If you have trouble with your VB code then ask a seperate question

Answer (score 1):

Group by the `name`. Then aggregate functions like `count()` apply to each group and not the complete table. With that you can check for names that occur more than once.

```
select min(id) as id,
       name
from your_table
group by name
having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: See my Update in topic please,

Answer (score 0):

You can use Rank() to get result .

```
select RANK() over(Order by Name) as ID,Name from TABLENAME
```

Have some information about Rank()

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms176102.aspx

Comment: agreed ! yes for sql server.